# Django Form field initial value on failed validation

Tags: django, django-forms

how do I set the value of a field element after a form has been submitted but has failed validation?  e.g.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    form.data['my_field'] = 'some different data'
```

I don't really want to put it in the view though and would rather have it as part of the form class.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    new_data = request.POST.copy()
    form = MyForm(data=new_data)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save() 
    else: 
        new_data['myField'] = 'some different data'
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 16):

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound) says:

> If you have a **bound** Form instance and want to **change the data** somehow, or if you want to bind an unbound Form instance to some data, **create another Form instance**. There is **no way to change data** in a Form instance. Once a Form instance has been created, you should consider its **data immutable**, whether it has data or not.

I cannot really believe that your code works. But ok. Based on the documentation I would do it this way:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.copy()
    form = MyForm(data)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save() 
    else: 
        data['myField'] = 'some different data'
        form = MyForm(initial=data)
```

Comment: Great solution. If you want to keep the errors of the vaildated form as well, you can use `new_form = MyForm(initial=data)     new_form._errors=form._errors     form=new_form`

Comment: @Michael I was able to keep errors following your suggestion- thanks, but  how to keep already submitted data in fields when form fails, to avoid user from entering the data again.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the form class like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    MY_VALUE = 'SOMETHING'
    myfield = forms.CharField(
        initial=MY_VALUE,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # If the form has been submitted, populate the disabled field
        if 'data' in kwargs:
            data = kwargs['data'].copy()
            self.prefix = kwargs.get('prefix')
            data[self.add_prefix('myfield')] = MY_VALUE
            kwargs['data'] = data

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The way it works, is it tests to see if any data has been passed in to the form constructor.  If it has, it copies it (the uncopied data is immutable) and then puts the initial value in before continuing to instantiate the form.