# replace values in form.data when form fails validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form field which requires a json object as its value when it is rendered.
When the form is submitted it returns a comma seperated string of ids as its value (not a json string).  however if the form does not validate i want to turn this string of ids back into a json string so it will display properly (is uses jquery to render the json object correctly).

how would i do this?

I was thinking of overwriting the form.clean method but when I tried to change self.data['fieldname'] I got the error 'This QueryDict instance is immutable'

and when i tried to change self.cleaned_data['fieldname'] it didn't make a difference to the value of the field.

Thanks

Comment: Was it necessary to create a new question for this? Basically it is the same as your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432421/django-form-field-initial-value-on-failed-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    new_data = request.POST.copy() 
    form = MyForm(data=new_data) 
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
    else:  
        new_data['myField'] = '[{'id':1,'value':some json object}]'
```

I did this in the view rather than on the form class.  I don't know if this is the best way to do it but its worked for me.  Doing request.POST.copy() allowed me to change the post variables which is one of the errors I was getting in the first place.

Hope this helps someone